# Get Customer information when Admin create sales order from backend

Tags: php, magento

I found a topic but it not solve my problem:
[Get customer details in backend admin panel order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475209/get-customer-details-in-backend-admin-panel-order)

I write a Observer **catalog_product_get_final_price** to change price when product load into cart.

```
<events>
            <catalog_product_get_final_price>
                <observers>
                    <Soft3S_Pricelistview_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                           <class>Soft3S_Pricelistview_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>get_final_price</method>
                    </Soft3S_Pricelistview_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_get_final_price>
        </events>
```

It works for frontend page.
I also want It works for backend page when an admin create Sales Order 
   In Observer.php, I try to get customer information:

```
public function get_final_price($observer)
{



{
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer_id=$customer->getEntityId();
    $customer_Firstname = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname();


//var_dump($customer);
  //  var_dump($customer_erpcode);

$discount = 0.3;

$event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct();
$product->original_price = $product->getPrice();

//$final_price = ($product->original_price ) * (1 – $discount);
        Mage::log('Log order number : '.print_r(Mage::getSingleton('core/session'),true).'  product code'.$product->getData('sku').'  '  , null, 'Trace unit price after load.log');
       print ($customer_id);

$product->setFinalPrice(300000);

return $this;
}
}
```

It prints out null value. 
Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. its working at my end.

```
    $sessionquoteId = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote()->getId();
    $sessionCustomerId = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($sessionquoteId)->getCustomerId();
    //$customerInfo = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sessionCustomerId);
```

Hope this help you.