# Which Event to be called when adding the products to order creation in magento admin?

Tags: magento

I have a scenario where I want to create the order from backend . But I want to call the api when we are selecting products for the order . I want to know which api we need to call when we add item for the order so I may call the API ?

I will really appreciate for any help .

Regards
Surjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sales_quote_add_item** Event will be occured when you add product to order from admin.

follow this steps.

Your config.xml will look like.

```
  <adminhtml> 
   <events>
        <sales_quote_add_item>
            <observers>
                <unique_event_name>
                    <class>module/observer</class>
                    <method>productlevelchanges</method>
                </unique_event_name>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_add_item>
    </events>
 </adminhtml>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 {
    public function productlevelchanges(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $ProductObject=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the customer information in the observer ? My scenario is to get the customer information for whom the order is etting placed and based on that fetch the prices from the api ...

Comment: Follow my another post to get customer detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029718/get-customer-information-when-admin-create-sales-order-from-backend/35030881#35030881

Answer (score 0):

Below event occure

```
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data
```

Create new field to order table when order created

trigger event on using event

```
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data event
```

it s params

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrderCreateModel();
$observer->getEvent()->getRequestModel();
$observer->getEvent()->getSession();
```